# C# XNA 4 Menu with buttons not work all

Tags: c#, button, menu, xna

Hi I making a main menu with sub menus in XNA 4/C#. I created a void to call the buttons, all work good but at click in buttons only work the first of the menu (this in all menus) .

The mouse over work in all, all text show, but no the clicks(only in the first of all menus. I tested to remove the Released check and the click work in all, but have the problem of release the click and press in next menu...

Here is the code:

```
    #region CheckforMenus
    //Level 0
    public static bool ismenuIntro = true;
    //Level 1
    public static bool ismenuMain = true;
    public static bool ismenuSinglePlayer = false;
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayer = false;
    public static bool ismenuChallenges = false;
    public static bool ismenuSettings = false;
    public static bool ismenuSelectProfile = false;
    public static bool ismenuCredits = false;
    public static bool ismenuExit = false;
    //Level 2
    //public static bool ismenuSinglePlayerP = false;
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayerJoin = false;
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayerHost = false;
    //Level 2 Settings
    public static bool ismenuSVideo = false;
    public static bool ismenuSSound = false;
    public static bool ismenuSControls = false;
    public static bool ismenuSLang = false;
    //Level 3
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby = false;
    #endregion
    public static MouseState previousMouseState;
    public static bool mbOverMouse = false;
    public static bool mbClickMouse = false;

    //The Button
    protected void mButton(SpriteFont mbFont, string mbName, string mbInfo, int mbType, int mbPosX, int mbPosY, string mbOldMenu, string mbNextMenu)
    {
            Vector2 origin1 = Main.fGUIMenu_Small.MeasureString(mbName);
            Rectangle clickableArea = new Rectangle(mbPosX, mbPosY, (int)origin1.X + 100, (int)origin1.Y);


            Point mousePos = new Point(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y);
            if (clickableArea.Contains(mousePos))
            {
                if (previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
                {

                    mbClickMouse = true;

                }
                else
                {
                    mbClickMouse = false;

                }
                mbOverMouse = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mbOverMouse = false;
            }

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            if (mbOverMouse)
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(mbFont, mbName, new Vector2(mbPosX, mbPosY), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(fGUIMenu_Small, mbName, new Vector2(20, 480), Color.White);
                spriteBatch.DrawString(fGUIMenu_Tiny, mbInfo, new Vector2(20, 500), Color.White);
            }
            else
            {
                spriteBatch.DrawString(mbFont, mbName, new Vector2(mbPosX, mbPosY), Color.White);
                mbOverMouse = false;
            }

            if (mbClickMouse)
            {
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuIntro") ismenuIntro = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMain") ismenuMain = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSinglePlayer") ismenuSinglePlayer = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayer") ismenuMultiplayer = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuChallenges") ismenuChallenges = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSettings") ismenuSettings = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSelectProfile") ismenuSelectProfile = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuCredits") ismenuCredits = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuExit") ismenuExit = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerJoin") ismenuMultiplayerJoin = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHost") ismenuMultiplayerHost = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSVideo") ismenuSVideo = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSSound") ismenuSSound = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSControls") ismenuSControls = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSLang") ismenuSLang = false;
                if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby") ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby = false;

                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuIntro") ismenuIntro = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMain") ismenuMain = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSinglePlayer") ismenuSinglePlayer = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayer") ismenuMultiplayer = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuChallenges") ismenuChallenges = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSettings") ismenuSettings = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSelectProfile") ismenuSelectProfile = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuCredits") ismenuCredits = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuExit") ismenuExit = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerJoin") ismenuMultiplayerJoin = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHost") ismenuMultiplayerHost = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSVideo") ismenuSVideo = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSSound") ismenuSSound = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSControls") ismenuSControls = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSLang") ismenuSLang = true;
                if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby") ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mbClickMouse = false;
            }


            spriteBatch.End();
            previousMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

    }
    //Here the menus
    //this is called in protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) 
    //as this.menuMain();
    protected void menuMain()
    {
        //Main
        //Level 0
        if (ismenuMain)
        {
            mButton(fGUIMenu_Small, "Singleplayer", "test text 1", 0, 20, 80, "ismenuMain", "ismenuSinglePlayer");
            mButton(fGUIMenu_Small, "Multiplayer", "test text 2", 0, 20, 80, "ismenuMain", "ismenuMultiplayer");

            spriteBatch.Begin();
            this.spriteBatch.DrawString(fGUIMenu_AMega, "Main Menu", new Vector2(10, 20), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
        else if (ismenuSinglePlayer)
        {
            mButton(fGUIMenu_Small, "MainMenu1", "hi 1", 0, 20, 80, "ismenuSinglePlayer", "ismenuMain");
            mButton(fGUIMenu_Small, "MainMenu2", "hi 1", 1, 20, 300, "ismenuSinglePlayer", "ismenuMain");
        }
        else if (ismenuMultiplayer)
        {
            mButton(fGUIMenu_Small, "MainMENU", "TEST TEST", 1, 20, 80, "ismenuMultiplayer", "ismenuMain");

        }
      }
```

Comment: have you thought about using a dictionary<string,bool> instead?

Comment: dictionary<string,bool> where and for what ?, the problem is in the "previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released" and "previousMouseState = Mouse.GetState();" ... where i use the dictionary?

Comment: mbNextMenu can have a wide variety of string values, you have a wide variety of bool variables, with a dictionary you could be able to set them based off `dictionary[mbNextMenu] = true;`

Comment: oh ok thanks, but this don't go to solve the problem...

Comment: Yeah sorry, bit busy at work right now otherwise i'd take a better look :) I'll try to look later

Comment: oh I have fixed this by another method, need define more checks of mbOverMouse,mbClickMouse & previousMouseState,Mouse.GetState() for the different calls... In some hours i reply, with the code, i dont have points to reply now...

Comment: -1 This really looks like a please debug my code request.

Comment: @ClassicThunder stackoverflow it's also intended to solve these kind of questions. -1 for you (if I could), +1 for the question.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas there is a faq you can go read to be disillusioned.

Comment: @ClassicThunder ok, sir, SO only answers theorical questions, have a nive day.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas There are practial questions that are not simply debugging poorly writen code. SO is about learning how to do something by answering questions about how to do things. Please tell me what are other visiters supposed to learn from this question?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

Need define bool mbOverMouse & bool mbClickMouse,mouseState,previousMouseState for different calls of the void. I've done it with this way:

```
    #region CheckforMenus
    //Level 0
    public static bool ismenuIntro = true;
    //Level 1
    public static bool ismenuMain = true;
    public static bool ismenuSinglePlayer = false;
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayer = false;
    public static bool ismenuChallenges = false;
    public static bool ismenuSettings = false;
    public static bool ismenuSelectProfile = false;
    public static bool ismenuCredits = false;
    public static bool ismenuExit = false;
    //Level 2
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayerJoin = false;
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayerHost = false;
    //Level 2 Settings
    public static bool ismenuSVideo = false;
    public static bool ismenuSSound = false;
    public static bool ismenuSControls = false;
    public static bool ismenuSLang = false;
    //Level 3
    public static bool ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby = false;
    #endregion

    //9 bools for 9 different types of buttons, dont need this, only 1 if you like
    bool[] mbOverMouse = new bool[9];
    bool[] mbClickMouse = new bool[9];
    MouseState[] mouseState = new MouseState[9];
    MouseState[] previousMouseState = new MouseState[9];

    void mButtonG(SpriteFont mbFont, string mbName, string mbInfo, int mbType, int mbPosX, int mbPosY, string mbOldMenu, string mbNextMenu)
    {

        int n = new int();
        n = mbType;
        //mbOverMouse[n] = false;
        //mbClickMouse[n] = false;
        Vector2 origin1 = Main.fGUIMenu_Small.MeasureString(mbName);
        Rectangle clickableArea = new Rectangle(mbPosX, mbPosY, (int)origin1.X + 100, (int)origin1.Y);


        Point mousePos = new Point(Mouse.GetState().X, Mouse.GetState().Y);
        if (clickableArea.Contains(mousePos))
        {
            mouseState[n] = Mouse.GetState();
            if (previousMouseState[n].LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && mouseState[n].LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            //mbType == 1 && mouseStatePrevious1.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && mouseStateCurrent1.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) //previousMouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Released && Mouse.GetState().LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed
            {

                mbClickMouse[n] = true;

            }
            else
            {
                mbClickMouse[n] = false;

            }
            mbOverMouse[n] = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mbOverMouse[n] = false;
        }

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        if (mbOverMouse[n])
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(mbFont, mbName, new Vector2(mbPosX, mbPosY), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(fGUIMenu_Small, mbName, new Vector2(20, 480), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(fGUIMenu_Tiny, mbInfo, new Vector2(20, 500), Color.White);
        }
        else
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(mbFont, mbName, new Vector2(mbPosX, mbPosY), Color.White);
            mbOverMouse[n] = false;
        }

        if (mbClickMouse[n])
        {
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuIntro") ismenuIntro = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMain") ismenuMain = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSinglePlayer") ismenuSinglePlayer = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayer") ismenuMultiplayer = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuChallenges") ismenuChallenges = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSettings") ismenuSettings = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSelectProfile") ismenuSelectProfile = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuCredits") ismenuCredits = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuExit") ismenuExit = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerJoin") ismenuMultiplayerJoin = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHost") ismenuMultiplayerHost = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSVideo") ismenuSVideo = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSSound") ismenuSSound = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSControls") ismenuSControls = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuSLang") ismenuSLang = false;
            if (mbOldMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby") ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby = false;

            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuIntro") ismenuIntro = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMain") ismenuMain = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSinglePlayer") ismenuSinglePlayer = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayer") ismenuMultiplayer = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuChallenges") ismenuChallenges = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSettings") ismenuSettings = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSelectProfile") ismenuSelectProfile = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuCredits") ismenuCredits = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuExit") ismenuExit = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerJoin") ismenuMultiplayerJoin = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHost") ismenuMultiplayerHost = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSVideo") ismenuSVideo = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSSound") ismenuSSound = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSControls") ismenuSControls = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuSLang") ismenuSLang = true;
            if (mbNextMenu == "ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby") ismenuMultiplayerHostlobby = true;
        }
        else
        {
            mbClickMouse[n] = false;
        }


        spriteBatch.End();
        previousMouseState[n] = mouseState[n];

    }
    protected void menuMain()
    {
        if (ismenuMain)
        {
            mbOverMouse[0] = false;
            mbClickMouse[0] = false;
            mButtonG(fGUIMenu_Small, "Singleplayer", "Here my text A", 0, 20, 80, "ismenuMain", "ismenuSinglePlayer");
            mButtonG(fGUIMenu_Small, "Multiplayer", "Here my text B", 0, 20, 110, "ismenuMain", "ismenuMultiplayer");
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            this.spriteBatch.DrawString(fGUIMenu_AMega, "Main Menu", new Vector2(10, 20), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();
        }
        else if (ismenuSinglePlayer)
        {
            mbOverMouse[0] = false;
            mbClickMouse[0] = false;
            mButtonG(fGUIMenu_Small, "Singleplayer", "Here my text A", 0, 20, 80, "ismenuSinglePlayer", "ismenuMain");
            mButtonG(fGUIMenu_Small, "Singleplayer", "Here my text B", 0, 20, 300, "ismenuSinglePlayer", "ismenuMain");
        }
        else if (ismenuMultiplayer)
        {
            mbOverMouse[0] = false;
            mbClickMouse[0] = false;
            mButtonG(fGUIMenu_Small, "Multiplayer", "Text", 0, 20, 110, "ismenuMultiplayer", "ismenuMain");

        }
    }
```